# How are TCP segments discarded after Maximum Segment Lifetime expires?

Tags: tcp, ttl

From RFC 793:

> To be sure that a TCP does not create a segment that carries a
> sequence number which may be duplicated by an old segment remaining in
> the network, the TCP must keep quiet for a maximum segment lifetime
> (MSL) before assigning any sequence numbers upon starting up or
> recovering from a crash in which memory of sequence numbers in use was
> lost.  For this specification the MSL is taken to be 2 minutes.

Seems contradicting what RFC 791 states:

> Network delays are incurred in other ways, e.g.,
> satellite links, which can add seconds of delay even though the Time
> to Live (TTL) is not decremented by a corresponding amount.  There is
> thus no enforcement mechanism to ensure that datagrams older than 120
> seconds are discarded.

I understand that MSL and TTL are used for different purposes reading [this](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/68468/is-tcps-msl-value-equivalent-to-ips-ttl-value).

Provided that TCP segments are forwarded between routers as IP packets (considering no fragmentation for the sake of easier understanding), and IP packets have a Time To Live (TTL) field that works as a hop count and from *RFC 791* seems like that is not time-related, how can routers in the network or TCP entities check that MSL is expired and therefore discard the segment?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question does not keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

They don't. The MSL is an *assumption*. We *assume* that no segment takes more than 2 minutes to be delivered, and therefore it is safe to reuse a segment number if we wait for 2 minutes or more.

Comment: I think I am missing something... What kind of safety comes from an arbitrary assumption? Is it assumed that after 2 minutes the segment will be delivered or discarded by some other way? If not, what stops an obsolete segment from reappearing back to the sender after being in the network for 5 minutes?

Comment: @GiulioTalarico why would it be in the network for 5 minutes?

Comment: Hypothetically some kind of bottleneck. Why not? My question is how can the sender be sure that an obsolete segment won't interfere after MSL?

Comment: @GiulioTalarico if an obsolete segment interferes with MSL then the sender calls up the network admin's boss and demands to know why the network is delaying packets for 5 minutes. That's how he knows. Do you know what "assumption" means?